# How can I understand these averages? (CMB context)

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmic-microwave-background

I am currently reading Prof. Mukhanov's book on "Foundations of Cosmology". In chapter 9 he is very briefly explaining *free streaming* and all of a sudden averages labeled with a direction vector $\bf l$ start appearing. Such as
$$\left\langle \frac{\delta T}{T}\right\rangle_{\bf l} = A_k \sin({\bf k\cdot x})\langle g\rangle_{\bf l}.$$
But he says beneath that expression that the brackets are an average over direction**s** but the LHS is still labeled by the direction vector $\bf l$, so how is this average defined?